# server call in react to c#

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, react-hooks, client-server

I am trying to read data from a database through a C# ASP.NET Core Web APP
When I get to routing it shows me the data [tha data in my link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCRa8.png)
But when I read it through React, it brings me an empty array, which means it can't read the data as well as C#
what is my problem???
I've been stuck on this for a long time, I've tried all kinds of different ways and it didn't work for me
If anyone can help me thanks!!

this my code in react:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Get() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        try {
            debugger
            axios.get('http://localhost:5029/api/Works')
               
                .then(response =>setData(response.json))
            console.log(data);
        } catch {
            alert("error")
        }
        console.log(data)
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {data.map((item) => (
                <p>{item}</p>
            ))}
        </>
    );
}
```

After I run the above code it shows me the following errors

[this is the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1VhJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Axios assumes json by default and doesn't have the methods fetch does. it should be

```js
axios.get("url").then(res => setData(res.data));
```

Reference: https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema

Allow me to explain those errors in more detail

initial render:
data = []

data.map doesn't run because empty array.

useEffect calls setData with response.json which doesn't exist, hence undefined.

now:
data = undefined

data.map throws error because undefined does not have a map method.